# mongoose set this field to true others will be false

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema like this:

```
const Config = new Schema({
    name: String,
    default: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    // ...
});
```

I want that:
If I create a document and set the field `default` of that document to true then the `default` field of all other documents will be set to `false` automatically.
Can I do that in `pre('save')` hook? and how to do that?

**Update**

More clearly, I want sth like this:

- document #1:

  ```
  {
      name: myseting1,
      default: false,
      // ...
  }
  ```

- document #2:

  ```
  {
      name: myseting2,
      default: true,
      // ...
  }
  ```

- document #3:

  ```
  {
      name: myseting3,
      default: false,
      // ...
  }
  ```

document #2 has `default` set to `true` only and others will be `false`.
And I want to do that in schema (such as `pre(save)` or sth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that can be done in pre-save hook provided by mongoose. It should be fairly strait, simply update all other documents and set there `default` to false in `pre-save` middle-ware then you can move on and save your new document. But make sure that document being saved has `default` set to `true`.

```
YourModelSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
 // do stuff
 if(this.default === true){
   this.constructor.update({},{$set: {default: false}},{multi: true})
   .then((cats) => {
     console.log(cats);
     next();// Calling next on after update has done, just to make sure all documents have been updated
   });
 }else{
   next();// if document default value is false then do normal stuff
 }

});
```

If you are not using ES6 promise with mongoose then you can write your update statement in mongoose way;

```
YourModelSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if(this.default === true){
    this.constructor.update({},{$set: {default: false}},{multi: true}).exec();
  }
  next();
}
```